# Flex Hbox Creation complete not invoked

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am trying to create an instance of `Hbox` like

```
obj = new HBox();
disp.addElement(obj); // disp object is border container but obj is mx component
```

this is the way I have been using a display object is adding to a parent container .

But it doesn't invoke the creation complete event.

I have been working on this last few days. Please help me.

Comment: You have to add it to the displayList for the component to be initialized. If you're a beginner Flex developer, I suggest you stick to using MXML.

Comment: No, I have been working since 2010 in flex .But Now facing this issue.This component is mx component but parent is spark.

Comment: In that case: how are you adding it to the displayList? Show some more code than just the constructor call (you can edit a question you previously wrote).

Comment: So where is the creationComplete event listener added? Generally, you need to add the event listener before you add the object to the stage. From the code you have shown, that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" initialize="windowedapplication1_initializeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;

            import mx.containers.HBox;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function windowedapplication1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent`enter code here`):void
            {
                var hbo:HBox=new HBox();
                hbo.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE,ff);
                b.addElement(hbo);
            }
            public function ff(e:FlexEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("created")
            }

        ]]>`enter code here`
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Group id="b">

    </s:Group>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```